# Lumen socialite google login, callback page "not found"

Tags: google-oauth, lumen, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to implement Socialite to do login with google in my website.

The page redirected to google auth page successfully. 
But then when auth success and the page redirect to my auth callback, i got the error "Page not found".

I found that in the callback url there is this scope `&scope=email+profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+openid` that made my auth callback route not found.

When I try to manually edit the scope in the callback url to `&scope=email+profile+openid`, my callback route called successfully and user logged in successfully.

Please help me to solve this problem, thanks all..

Edit:
this is my callback route

```
    $router->get('auth/google_callback', 
    'UserCustomerController@authGoogleCallback');
```

Answer (score 0):

config/services.php

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => 'http://your-callback-url/login/google/callback',
],
```

make callback Route

```
Route::get('login/google/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```